# Convert Character into Date (R)

Tags: r, data-transform

Here I have a chr column data$month which initially was like this "1980m10".
I'm trying to convert it into a date format so I can plot line graph for stock returns.
however when I try

```
as.Date(data$month, "%Ym%m")
```

it returns me only NA values.

I have tried to convert the column into more clear format

```
data$year = substr(data$month,1,4)
data$mon = substr(data$month,6,8)

library(stringr)

data$month = paste(data$year,'-',data$mon)

as.Date(data$month, "%y - %m")
```

However still it returns me only NA values. Idk how to solve this problem.
I have tried without format:
but it says the character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding a default day to the date, e.g. `01`, to make it a formal date:

```r
data$year <- substr(data$month, 1, 4)
data$mon <- substr(data$month, 6, 8)
data$date <- as.Date(paste(data$year, data$mon, "01", sep="-"))
```

Comment: Kylian I appreciate your comment! However, I need it to be monthly based!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the package `?stringr` containing the `str_sub` function

```
R> str_sub(data$month,1,4) 
[1] "1980"
```

Another potential package is the `?substr` package. Just take a look at both. As your format is ambiguous I would propose to use a function that simply takes the first 4 characters.